# Is it possible to conduct a coefficient test within a multiple regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, p-value, regression-coefficients, bias

In an analysis of employment, a difference in means test shows that gender is important.

Multiple logistic regression using several specifications robustly identifies a positive coefficient on gender, but the magnitude varies wildly and the p-value is consistently large (.5 < p < .95).

I would like to take the average coefficient estimate despite the fact that the p-values are large. I would feel more comfortable with this average if I could somehow demonstrate that, within the context of some model a "p-value with respect to beta" is less than 0.5 instead of showing that a "p-value with respect to zero" is greater than 0.5.

As an aside related to motivation: While it is now generally accepted that p-value selection using traditional levels including 0.1 are arbitrary, I am uncomfortable with p > 0.5 as it seems to me to state "it is more likely that the true effect is close to zero rather than close to the estimated coefficient", ie p'(B) > p(B), and I am concerned about included variable bias with such factors.

Comment: I disagree that the p-value says the effect is more likely to be near zero than near the estimate. Logistic regression parameters are (usually) estimated via maximum likelihood, so there is a sense in which the estimate is the most likely value!

Comment: "but the magnitude varies wildly and the p-value is consistently large (.5 < p < .95)" is a great description of any explanatory variable that is not associated with the outcome.

Comment: @Dave is it not straightforward that if `p > 0.5` then `p(B) < p'(B)`? Do they not sum to 1?

Comment: Yes, complements sum to $1$, but what is B?

Comment: Ah, I was using B as shorthand for any particular beta, a coefficient estimate presented in a regression summary.

Comment: Are you seeking to test the hypothesis that $\beta = k$ for some value of $k$ other than 0? It's a bit hard to know what exactly you want to do. "p-value with respect to beta" is an unclear term because p-values are not usually described with respect to something; they are the probability of a result as extreme or more extreme than the one you found were the null hypothesis to be true.

Comment: @Noah `Are you seeking to test the hypothesis that β=k for some value of k other than 0?` Yes! Precisely. I agree my description is unclear - I imagine a substantial part of my lack of knowledge of an answer has to do with framing the question incorrectly. I also agree this would not be the normal thing that a p-value means, etc.